# getting error:-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable

Tags: apache-hadoop, java, hive

I am trying to connect to hive from java but getting error. I searched in google but not got any helpfull solution. I have added all jars also.

The code is:-

```
package mypackage;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class HiveJdbcClient {


private static String driver = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, 
       ClassNotFoundException {
 Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
 try {
 Class.forName(driver);
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1);
}

Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://master:10000 /default", "", "");
Statement state = connect.createStatement();
String tableName = "mytable";
state.executeQuery("drop table " + tableName);
ResultSet res=state.executeQuery("ADD JAR /home/hadoop_home/hive/lib /hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
res = state.executeQuery("create table tweets (id BIGINT,created_at     STRING,source STRING,favorited BOOLEAN,retweet_count INT,retweeted_status STRUCT<text:STRING,user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,entities STRUCT<urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,text STRING,user  STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING,friends_count:INT,followers_count:INT,statuses_count:INT,verified:BOOLEAN,utc_offset:INT,time_zone:STRING>,in_reply_to_screen_name STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets'");


String show = "show tables";
System.out.println("Running show");
res = state.executeQuery(show);
if (res.next()) {
  System.out.println(res.getString(1));
}


String describe = "describe " + tableName;
System.out.println("Running describe");
res = state.executeQuery(describe);
while (res.next()) {
  System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
}

}
}
```

I am getting these errors:-

run:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hive/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/modules/weld-osgi-bundle.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.configureConnection(HiveConnection.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:106)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at dp.HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 8 more
Java Result: 1

Comment: Flagged the question as it has nothing to do with data science. Probably [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) would be the right place for this.

Comment: A simple Google search of the first error line would take you to a [StackOverflow thread where they discuss this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings) or [another SO thread where they solve it again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896243/maven-slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. One jar file was missing now it is solved. 
This file was missing.
hadoop-common-2.1.0-beta.jar